# Cors error with JWT sent from frontend when using axios

Tags: spring-boot, axios, jwt, cors

When doing a request, that needs a token, from the frontend of my application using axios, with these parameters:

[Network request parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPGEa.png)

It appears this error of the CORS policy:

[Frontend error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBtcN.png)

In the backend appears this:

[Parameters of the request as seen in the SpringBoot debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OL4k.png)

[Couldn't find user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dm9t.png)

The thing is that in the backend I already have a CORS configuration where I allow the authorization header:

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization")
                .maxAge(3600); // Max age of the preflight request in seconds
    }
```

In fact, if I try the protected requests from Postman, they work well:

[Login in postman, seeing the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak8nx.png)

[Doing a get request using the bearer token works as it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N2in.png)

This is the code in the frontend of the axios request:

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

export async function getRequest(URL, token) {
    let response;
    if (token == undefined || token == null) {
        console.log("Sin token " + token)
        response = await axiosClient.get(URL, {
            validateStatus: function (status) {
                return true;
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log("Con token " + token)
        response = await axiosClient.get(URL, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
            validateStatus: function (status) {
                return true;
            }
        })
    }

    console.log(response)

    return response.data
}
```

I think that what is happening is that, when using Postman, there isn't the "Options request" stage (the preflight I think it's called), only the request I'm doing which has the token:

[Parameters of the debug mode of an example request made from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FjLU.png)

But when doing the request from the frontend, because of the CORS policy, first it does the request as an Options and, after it is secured, then does the real request, sending all the info, and because in the Options request there isn't any token, it fails.

[Options parameters as seen in the network page of the front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXyx9.png)

What should I do?

I tried to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to my CORS config in the backend, as the error in the frontend says

`.allowedHeaders("Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")`

but it didn`t work

Comment: A 401 response to a preflight request suggests that you haven't stacked your middleware in a correct order: more specifically, you likely have some auth middleware in front of the CORS middleware, which cannot work because preflight requests are not authenticated.

Comment: The 401 is being returned by the backend server itself. Because the preflight doesn't have the token, the server can't authorize the request so denies the access

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The CORS middleware should intercept the preflight request and reply with an appropriate preflight response, without even letting that request reach the handler that requires authentication.

Comment: I solved the problem adding `http.cors()` to the security configuration. That enables a cors filter that bypass the authorization checks when an OPTIONS request arrives. For caution I put that line before the adding of the authorization filter, as you said.